# install4j console mode can't choose language to install. Error message " '9' is not recognized as an internal or external command "

Tags: console, windows-installer, install4j

We are using install4j to generate a Windows installer for our application.
We would like our users to use the console mode for installations on Windows.

Run command as "xxx.exe -c"
but when I enter number to choose the language,
will get the error " '9' is not recognized as an internal or external command "

So we change install4j configuration to enable the "Windows console executable" option.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx945.png)
and run command "xxx.exe -c" again

Working fine.
And can enter number choose the language to install our application
but we will see the other console windows when I install (that is ok, we don't care)

However, when I double-clicked the xxx.exe to install
we can countinue install our application by GUI mode
but we will see the other console windows when I install

1.
If enable the "Windows console executable",
we can install by console mode and can double-clicked the xxx.exe to install our application with only GUI windows(don't show the console windows)

2.
If disable the "Windows console executable",
we can install by console mode and can enter number to choose language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Windows GUI executable cannot attach its input to the console that is was started from. You have to start the installer like this:

```
start /wait installer.exe -c
```

Then the installer is put in the foreground.